# Async false freeze website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

My website always freze with async false. I need to wait confirmation for execute script.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(),
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var conf = data;
    }
});

if(conf == "ok")
{
   alert('ok');
}
```

What is the good model for use this with async true please? I have tested with return but not work.

Edit:

```
 $(function(){
        window.wheel = {

            init: {},

            wheelof: function() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
 }
 }

        window.wheel.init();
});
```

Comment: Most AJAX request should be async with a callback function.  Non-async requests tie up the browser and give the user a bad experience.

Comment: This technique implements a promise design pattern for async requests.  You should define an error handler as well. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 5):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(),
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        var conf = data;
        check(conf);      
    }
});
```

Pass data values to separate function after success.

```
function check(conf){
if(conf == "ok")
 {
   alert('ok');
 }
}
```

Comment: You mean `async: true`?

Comment: Why the extra function? You can just do it all in the success.

Comment: @CharlesSmartt, Yes OP can do checking data inside success also.

Comment: Thanks you guy but not work i use $(function(){ window.wheel = { wheel: function{ AJAX } } i have edit my post sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(),
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        var conf = data;
        if ( conf === "ok" ) {
           alert( "ok" )        
        }    
    }
});
```

Comment: Why assign the value to a variable when data is conf? Just do data==="ok".

Comment: Thanks you but not work i have edit my post, with window.wheel i have bug

Comment: You can directly do data === 'ok'

Comment: Could you elaborate the window.wheel issue a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but didn't see any good answer, so here is mine from my experience:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize()
})
.done(function(data){
    var conf = data;
    check(conf);
});

function check(conf){
    if(conf == "ok"){
        alert('ok');
    }
}
```

This way the user experience doesn't suffer from unresponsive webpage. Using `asynnc: false` is not a good solution.